# Get sum of "quantity" when grouping by a property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of my class Products.

```
List<Products> lstProducts;

public class Products
{
    public string Types {get; set;}
    public string Quantity {get; set;}
}
```

having following items in my list:

```
 Types      Quantity
 Silver       2
 Gold         1  
 Silver       1
```

I want to return a Dictionary having Types and their Total Count of Quantity:

```
(Silver, 3)
(Gold, 1)
```

I tried following code but it gives me wrong count, what am I doing wrong?

```
lstProducts.GroupBy(x => x.Types).
    ToDictionary(g => g.Key.ToString(), g => g.Count().ToString());
```

Comment: @ArunPratap I just dont want the Count of `Types`. I want the total of their `Quantity` as explained in example. My code doesn't return that

Comment: Do you mean you want a Sum? If so, use a [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.7.2) and keep your numbers typed as integers or whatever is appropriate, rather than string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Quantity`  is of datatype `string` so you need to first convert it to `int` and then apply `Sum` to calculate total `Quantity` of particular `Type`.

```
var result = lstProducts
  .GroupBy(x => x.Types)
  .ToDictionary(
     g => g.Key.ToString(), 
     g => g
       .Select(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Quantity) ? Convert.ToInt32(x.Quantity) : 0)
       .Sum()
       .ToString());

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " - " + item.Value);

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 var data = lstProducts.GroupBy(i => i.Types)
                                  .Select(x => {
                                          var ret = x.First();
                                          ret.Quantity = x.Sum(xt => Convert.ToInt32(xt.Quantity)).ToString();
                                          return ret;
                                         }).ToList();
```